# Strange TRY CATCH behavior that occurs when inserting records inside a WHILE LOOP

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, transactions

Below is the code I'm running (ready to copy-paste into SQL Server). I'm essentially trying to use a WHILE LOOP to insert records from one table into a new table one-by-one, and log the results of each insert using a third table. Once I can resolve this issue, this code will be tweaked and used in several stored procedures.

Here is the code:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --Create dummy tables

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #OldTable
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #NewTable
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #LoggingTable

    CREATE TABLE #OldTable (
        ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        ,OldValue varchar(64)
    )

    INSERT INTO #OldTable
    VALUES
        ('1')
        ,('2')
        ,('3')
        ,('Four')
        ,('Five')
        ,('6')
        ,('Seven')

    CREATE TABLE #NewTable (
        ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        ,NewValue int
    )

    CREATE TABLE #LoggingTable (
        ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        ,OldTableID int NULL
        ,NewTableID int NULL
        ,InsertStatus varchar(MAX)
    )

    --Begin insert loop

    DECLARE @currentID int = NULL

    DECLARE THIS_CURSOR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT ID FROM #OldTable ORDER BY ID

    OPEN THIS_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM THIS_CURSOR INTO @currentID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            --Perform insert
            INSERT INTO #NewTable
            OUTPUT @currentID, INSERTED.ID, 'Insert successful' INTO #LoggingTable (OldTableID, NewTableID, InsertStatus)
            SELECT CAST(OldValue AS int) FROM #OldTable WHERE ID = @currentID

            FETCH NEXT FROM THIS_CURSOR INTO @currentID
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            INSERT INTO #LoggingTable (OldTableID, NewTableID, InsertStatus) VALUES (@currentID, NULL, 'Error occurred during insert operation')
            FETCH NEXT FROM THIS_CURSOR INTO @currentID
        END CATCH   
    END

    CLOSE THIS_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE THIS_CURSOR

    SELECT * FROM #OldTable
    SELECT * FROM #NewTable
    SELECT * FROM #LoggingTable

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'An error has occurred';

    -- Test if the transaction is uncommittable.  
    IF XACT_STATE() = -1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. Rolling back transaction.'; 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
    END;

    -- Test if the transaction is committable.  
    IF XACT_STATE() = 1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT 'The transaction is committable. Committing transaction.';
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
    END;

    THROW;
END CATCH
```

Here is the error message I'm getting:

> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

The offending line appears to be this one:

```sql
INSERT INTO #LoggingTable (OldTableID, NewTableID, InsertStatus) VALUES (@currentID, NULL, 'Error occurred during insert operation')
```

However if I comment out this line (which I still need!) it just moves to another line in the code, which usually means there's something else going on. I've already done a thorough search online and I'm still not sure what the cause of this error is.

The strangest part about this error is if you remove the outer `TRY CATCH` and `TRANSACTION`, the script runs exactly as intended with no issues; however, this isn't a viable solution IMHO due to needing proper error catching and transaction handling once it's encompassed in a stored procedure.

Comment: Transaction semantics and writing to log tables are . . . not really compatible.  Check information on XACT_STATE.  I think I've worked around this in the past by writing things to a file (argghh!)

Comment: Probably see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/867416/Logging-from-inside-a-transaction. Also note that it's not the `INSERT INTO #LoggingTable` that creates the issue, it's the fact that the transaction is in uncommittable state, and any persistable operations will fail, including the `INSERT INTO #NewTable` on the next iteration.

Comment: Even if I get rid of the logging requirement and remove the TRY, CATCH block from the loop, I still can't find a way to allow the loop to finish instead of exiting the loop the moment the first insert fails. I basically just want the loop to skip to the next step if there's an error. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You would have to move your transaction inside the loop so that each pass through the loop is a separate transaction. But that begs the question...why are you using a cursor for inserts like this?

Comment: @SeanLange That's actually one of the first things I tried. I put a BEGIN, COMMIT and ROLLBACK TRAN within the loop but anytime I would roll back, it wouldn't roll back to the the last pass but rather the entire procedure (as far as I could tell anyways). As for your second question, you're right. I'm using a cursor for inserts so I can record the status of each insert individually. Without this requirement it doesn't make much sense as there are better ways to do this.

Comment: You would have to restructure quite a bit of this. Inside each iteration you need a try catch along with a transaction. Basically the body of your loop has to encapsulate one entire insert process to accomplish what you are trying to do here. But honestly from what I see you don't need a transaction around this at all. All you are doing is a single insert each pass through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved "COMMIT TRANSACTION" couple rows up and it works fine (The exception is thrown because it is trying to write to a table within the catch block before rolling back the transaction) :

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --Create dummy tables
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #OldTable;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #NewTable;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #LoggingTable;

    CREATE TABLE #OldTable
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        OldValue VARCHAR(64)
    );

    INSERT INTO #OldTable
    VALUES
    ('1'),
    ('2'),
    ('3'),
    ('Four'),
    ('Five'),
    ('6'),
    ('Seven');

    CREATE TABLE #NewTable
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        NewValue INT
    );

    CREATE TABLE #LoggingTable
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        OldTableID INT NULL,
        NewTableID INT NULL,
        InsertStatus VARCHAR(MAX)
    );

    --Begin insert loop

    DECLARE @currentID INT = NULL;

    DECLARE THIS_CURSOR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT ID
    FROM #OldTable
    ORDER BY ID;

    OPEN THIS_CURSOR;
    FETCH NEXT FROM THIS_CURSOR
    INTO @currentID;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            --Perform insert
            INSERT INTO #NewTable
            OUTPUT @currentID,
                   INSERTED.ID,
                   'Insert successful'
            INTO #LoggingTable
            (
                OldTableID,
                NewTableID,
                InsertStatus
            )
            SELECT CAST(OldValue AS INT)
            FROM #OldTable
            WHERE ID = @currentID;

            FETCH NEXT FROM THIS_CURSOR
            INTO @currentID;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            INSERT INTO #LoggingTable
            (
                OldTableID,
                NewTableID,
                InsertStatus
            )
            VALUES
            (@currentID, NULL, 'Error occurred during insert operation');
            FETCH NEXT FROM THIS_CURSOR
            INTO @currentID;
        END CATCH;
    END;

    CLOSE THIS_CURSOR;
    DEALLOCATE THIS_CURSOR;

    SELECT *
    FROM #OldTable;
    SELECT *
    FROM #NewTable;
    SELECT *
    FROM #LoggingTable;


    SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'An error has occurred';

    -- Test if the transaction is uncommittable.  
    IF XACT_STATE() = -1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. Rolling back transaction.';
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

    -- Test if the transaction is committable.  
    IF XACT_STATE() = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The transaction is committable. Committing transaction.';
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END;

    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: This gave me enough insight on the problem that I was finally able to arrive at a solution. I decided to restructure my transactions to take into account the table locking of the #LoggingTable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I think the transaction in here is just making things more complicated than they need to be. There is an implicit transaction around every DML statement. The body of your cursor is nothing more than an insert statement with a catch block if the insert fails. I removed a bunch of extraneous code dealing with explicit transactions and your example works perfectly.

```
--Create dummy tables

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #OldTable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #NewTable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #LoggingTable

CREATE TABLE #OldTable (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,OldValue varchar(64)
)

INSERT INTO #OldTable
VALUES
    ('1')
    ,('2')
    ,('3')
    ,('Four')
    ,('Five')
    ,('6')
    ,('Seven')

CREATE TABLE #NewTable (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,NewValue int
)

CREATE TABLE #LoggingTable (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,OldTableID int NULL
    ,NewTableID int NULL
    ,InsertStatus varchar(MAX)
)

--Begin insert loop

DECLARE @currentID int = NULL

DECLARE THIS_CURSOR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT ID FROM #OldTable ORDER BY ID

OPEN THIS_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM THIS_CURSOR INTO @currentID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        --Perform insert
        INSERT INTO #NewTable
        OUTPUT @currentID, INSERTED.ID, 'Insert successful' INTO #LoggingTable (OldTableID, NewTableID, InsertStatus)
        SELECT CAST(OldValue AS int) FROM #OldTable WHERE ID = @currentID

        FETCH NEXT FROM THIS_CURSOR INTO @currentID
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO #LoggingTable (OldTableID, NewTableID, InsertStatus) VALUES (@currentID, NULL, 'Error occurred during insert operation')
        FETCH NEXT FROM THIS_CURSOR INTO @currentID
    END CATCH   
END

close THIS_CURSOR
deallocate THIS_CURSOR

SELECT * FROM #OldTable
SELECT * FROM #NewTable
SELECT * FROM #LoggingTable
```